# Removing repetitions in one column and iterate lines to collapse in second column

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I am looking for a way to generate some statistics on my model predictions.
On the left I have true values and on the right I have predictions.
My true values are over an interval so I want to condense them into a single value for each interval and know which predictions were made.
I think I need to do something like "uniq" to the first column and iterate each line of the second column until the value changes in the first column.
I would imagine that awk would be very good at this using $1 and $2 to treat the columns but the iteration of the second column without losing the info in the first column is where I am stuck. It is worth while to note that the values in the first column can occur many times and I want them repeated in each interval just not in sequence.
I can accept any code that is in shell or python.

Example Input:

```
1   1
1   0
1   1
2   2
2   2
1   1
3   3
3   3
3   2
3   3
2   3
2   2
2   1
```

Example output:

```
1   1 0 1
2   2 2
1   1
3   3 3 2 3
2   3 2 1
```

Comment: What have you thought of so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1{cr="\n"}L!=$1{printf "%s%s ",cr,$1;L=$1}{printf " %s" ,$2}END{print ""}' input
```

**Result**

```
1  1 0 1 
2  2 2 
1  1 
3  3 3 2 3 
2  3 2 1
```

**Explanation**

`NR>1{cr="\n"}`: `cr` or *carriage return*: will be *null* until the first record is processed (`NR>1`).

`L!=$1{printf "%s%s  ",cr,$1;L=$1}`: If the `L` *Last key* differs from the current (`$1`) it prints *cr* (null at first record) the current key `$1`, and stores it's value in `L` as the Last key processed.

`{printf " %s" ,$2}`: Just show the second column of *each record*.

`END{print ""}`: Print a final *carriage return* when all records are processed.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version in bash:

```
#/bin/bash
while read a b; do
    if [ $a != "$val" ]; then
        [ -n "$val" ] && echo $val $pred
        val=$a
        pred=$b
    else
        pred="$pred $b"
    fi
done <inputfile
[ -n "$val" ] && echo $val $pred
```